# storing selected value to enumtype

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I a have a page that has enumtype. the following is the code in aspx.cs inside the pageload

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                RegardingObject();
     ListItem selectedType = dropRegarding.Items.FindByValue(Event.RegardingObjectType.ToString());
                    if(selectedType!=null)
                    {
                        selectedType.Selected = true;
                    }
```

the following to populate dropdownlist

```
      private void RegardingObject()
       {
           dropRegarding.Items.Add(new ListItem("UnknownOrNone","0"));
           dropRegarding.Items.Add(new ListItem("LiveTrack", "10"));
           dropRegarding.Items.Add(new ListItem("Activity", "11"));
       }
```

while saving it back i am using

```
   Event.RegardingObjectType = (EnumTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumTypes),
                                        dropRegarding.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

getting cannot implicitly convert type 'datacontracts.enumtypes' to 'datacontracts.enumtypes.regardingobjecttype'

in datacontracts.enumtypes.cs i have

```
    public class EnumTypes
{

    public enum RegardingObject
    {
        UnknownOrNone = 0,
       LiveTrack = 10,
        Activity = 11
    }

}
```

Comment: What is Event.RegardingObjectType?   For clarity don't use the same name for enum, method, and property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `EnumTypes` isn't an enum, `RegardingObject` is:

```
Event.RegardingObjectType = (EnumTypes.RegardingObject)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumTypes.RegardingObject),
    dropRegarding.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks Michael i have regardingobjecttype for something else too so enumtypes.regardingobjecttype worked

Answer (score 0):

this does it

```
    Event.RegardingObjectType = (EnumTypes.RegardingObjectType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumTypes.RegardingObjectType),
                                         dropRegarding.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

its EnumTypes.regardingobjecttype instead of enumtypes